# find the mobile number and print using regular expression using php

Tags: php, regex

```
<div>
<span onclick="find('test','Call Now!');phone.open('ayyappa','970-363-9869',32659874,0)" >
Call Now!
</span>
<span onclick="find('test','Call Now!');phone.open('ayyappa','949-858-3181',38596380,0)" >
Call Now!
</span>
</div>
```

expected out put :
949-858-3181 and 38596380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific use, the regex will be `(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})\',(\d{8})`

```
preg_match('/(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})\',(\d{8})/', $input_html, $matches);
$n1 = $matches[1];
$n2 = $matches[2];
```

`n1` will have the phone number and `n2` the second number.

Answer (score 0):

This will capture digits until a `'` or `,` so even if the dashes are placed differently it will work.

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+.*?)['|,]/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

You have to click preg_match_all to see the result I had in mind.
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fOc